# Why I get "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cordova

I want to use [lolapi](https://github.com/emmorts/lolapi), so I went with my terminal to folder where project is and did `npm install lolapi`.

My code is a really simple cordova app:

**HTML:**

```
<body>
    <div class="app">
        <h1>&nbsp;&nbsp;Lol App</h1>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lolJ.js"></script>
</body>
```

**JavaScript (lolJ.js):**

```
var options = {
  useRedis: true,
  hostname: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 6379,
  cacheTTL: 7200
};

var lolapi = require('lolapi')('***-***-***-***-***', 'euw', options);

lolapi.setRateLimit(10, 500);

var summonerName = 'Wickd';
lolapi.Summoner.getByName(summonerName, function (error, summoner) {
  if (error) throw error;
  /* summoner object
  { Wickd:
    {
      id: 71500,
      name: 'Wickd',
      profileIconId: 613,
      summonerLevel: 30,
      revisionDate: 1408199475000
    }
  } */
  console.log(summoner);
  console.log(summoner[summonerName]);
  var summonerId = summoner[summonerName].id;
  lolapi.Summoner.getRunes(summonerId, function (error, runes) {
    if (error) throw error;
    // do something with runes
  })
});
```

I replaced `Wickd` with my lol username, but still nothing happens.

As you can see I'm really new to this, so please, any guide will be great

Thanks

Comment: Because you are trying to this in browser, but example on the GitHub page for NodeJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `require` syntax is what's referred to as [CommonJS](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/CommonJS), the default way of how you load modules within Node.js environments.

In order to use the `require` syntax in a browser environment you'd need to use tools like [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) which handles this for you by bundling your application together with your dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, most definately. You should use Browserify as part of your build step and serve your bundled JavaScript file.

Comment: I looked into it and found it really interesting, now I have a little problem with lolapi U_U. `$ browserify lolJ.js > bundle.js
Error: Cannot find module 'hiredis' from '/Users/me/node_modules/lolapi/node_modules/redis/lib/parser'` but when I look into folder I can see hiredis.js there